# Storing some objects in Cloud Firestore as fields in a document vs storing as documents in a subcollection?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to store multiple objects in Cloud Firestore? Which of the following approaches is more efficient in terms of cost and performance:

1. Store the objects as fields in a document
2. Store the objects as documents in a subcollection?

Would it also depend on

if

1. I have to retrieve all these objects from the database at once

or if

2. I have to retrieve only a specific object from the database at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what kind and the number of documents you want to store.

In Cloud Firestore, the unit of storage is the document. A document is a lightweight record that contains fields, which map to values.

Complex, nested objects in a document are called maps. For example, you could structure the user's name in your database, like this:

```
name
 |
 --- first: "fistName"
 |
 --- last: "lastName"
```

You may notice that documents look a lot like JSON. In fact, they basically are. There are some differences (for example, documents support extra data types and are limited in size to 1 MB), but in general, you can treat documents as lightweight JSON records.

From the official doc:

> Cloud Firestore is schemaless, so you have complete freedom over what fields you put in each document and what data types you store in those fields. Documents within the same collection can all contain different fields or store different types of data in those fields. However, it's a good idea to use the same fields and data types across multiple documents, so that you can query the documents more easily.
>
> A collection contains documents and nothing else. It can't directly contain raw fields with values, and it can't contain other collections.

Imagine you have chat rooms, decide how to store your messages. You might not want to store them in the chat room's document. Documents in Cloud Firestore should be lightweight, and a chat room could contain a large number of messages. However, you can create additional collections within your chat room's document, as subcollections.

Regarding your last questions, definitely the second solution, store the objects as documents within a subcollection.

But more details about this topic, please see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model).

Comment: Ohh thanks! But won't it be benificial if i store the multiple objects as fields in a document? Like, I can retrieve all the objects with a single document read? So wont that cost me less than downloading multiple documents in a subcollection?

Comment: As i wrote you in my answer, this kind of objects in a document are called `maps`. Firestore scales automatically when is composed of many small size documents. But remember, documents are limited in size at 1 MB. If you create separate documents there is no limitation regarding the number of documents. See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) Firestore limitations.

Comment: Some more information about your use case would definitely help.  For example, if you need to be able to query multiple documents with a particular field value, then you should use maps.  Bear in mind the document size restrictions.  The more elagant way to achieve your result may be to use sub-collections.  It will scale much better and provider greater access control.  Your question is very generic.  If cost is your main concern, then I would consider that you'd have to read a huge number of documents before you'd need to worry too much

Comment: Hey Mamo, I want to use objects structure in cloud Firestore and the values in it are read from the arrays i.e array elements are to be stored in cloud Firestore.Here is the start code for it.

Comment: @DivyaGalla I cannot see any code. But in order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you.